# Is JVM capable of reusing the split results for the same String objects?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

My question regards a situation when a split or other String  method is called multiple times for the same String object.

Does any popular JVM implementations optimize such calls by storing the results in the memory to be reused later?

It could work like that:
Because of the Strings immutable nature and existence of the String pool an expression

```
String resource = "A:B:C";
String[] resourceArr = resource.split(":");
```

would use the same String object references to "A:B:C" and ":" every time it is used. The JVM could match a stored result using those references and provide it without performing the actual parsing.

Comment: I seriously doubt that such an optimization is done by any VM. What would be the point? If you go this far, you'd need to cache pretty much all methods.

Comment: I doubt that this is optimized because it's very easy to optimize by the programmer. Once you've split the string once there is no reason to split it again you can just use the array that was created the first time.

Comment: In a related note: `String.split()` in the OpenJDK is pure Java (no native calls involved in the actual logic). You can just check the source code to see what it does (hint: there's no caching).

Comment: Only strings that are explicitly interned are in pool (see String.intern() method). The problem with re-use is that it would prevent unnecessary parts from being garbage collected so GC logic is significantly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  That'd be tremendously wasteful of memory -- it'd be extremely rare that the same split results would need to get reused, much less the overhead on a per-String basis -- and it's much better for the programmer to selectively decide when to cache such results, the "normal way."

Answer (score 3):

It does optimise the same way the `substring` is optimised, since `split` is using `substring`:

```
public String substring (int start, int end) {
    if (start == 0 && end == count)
        return this;
    // NOTE last character not copied!
    // Fast range check.
    if (0 <= start && start <= end && end <= count) {
        return new String (offset + start, end - start, value);
    }
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

Note, how `substring` returns a range of characters between offset+start and end-start of the same string. In other words, the split substrings are effectively pointers to the same memory allocated by the original string.

Comment: Just dug to this code and wanted to answer. Actual call stack is split(String regex, int limit) -> split(CharSequence input, int limit) -> subSequence(int beginIndex, int endIndex) -> substring (int start, int end) -> String(int offset, int count, char value[])